# Comparing the discriminative ability of two comorbidity indices for mortality: should I go for ROC and AUC?

Tags: survival, roc, auc, discriminant-analysis, mortality

Different comorbidity indices are widely used tools for describing patients' comorbidity statuses. A large score = many illnesses, and vice versa. I would like to compare two such indices to examine which better predicts one-year mortality.

Studies have used different estimates to describe "discriminative ability". Which of them should I choose for my goal? Plotting a ROC and calculating AUCs for both indices? Recommendations for R packages are also very welcome. Finally, are there any good Bayesian ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotting the ROC will not help in any way.  Computing AUROC (aka c-index; c=concordance probability) helps as a secondary measure but not as a primary measure because of its insensitivity---it doesn't properly reward extreme predictions that are correct.  The gold standard is the log likelihood and quantities derived from it such as pseudo $R^2$.  Another excellent metric is the variance of the predicted values (here on the P(death) scale).  I deal with these in detail at fharrell.com/post/addvalue.

Make sure you take a look at the Elixhauser and Schweiss comorbidity indexes and avoid the Charlson index, which contains an arithmetic error.

Comment: I’ve seen you post a couple of times that AUC is nice but not quite the gold standard. Could you please expand on this? The way I’ve read this is that AUC is a nice absolute gauge of performance in the sense that we know $0.95$ is usually really good and $0.55$ is pretty bad, but it’s not quite the right metric for comparing models, only to decide if one model on its own has solid predictive power.